# round corners not working in IE9

Tags: html, css

I have a round corner dialog box which works fine in Firefox but the round corners are not there in IE9.

I am using the following code:

```
            #dialog-box {
/* css3 drop shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
/* css3 border radius */
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
background:#eee;
width: 1000px;
height:900px;
/* make sure it has the highest z-index */
position:absolute;
z-index:5000;
/* hide it by default */
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your border radius rules are specifically for Webkit and Firefox alone.  You have no radius rules for any other browser.  See answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the webkit and mozilla extensions, you need to use the "standardized" `border-radius` property:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff974085.aspx

W3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

Answer (score 2):

Please add this also

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px;
```

-moz-border-radius   - Firefox

-webkit-border-radius - Safari 3,4

border-radius  - Opera 10.5, IE 9, Chrome, Safari 5

Answer (score 1):

The correct rule is `border-radius: 5px;`